# Use non-managed code (C) in c#

Tags: c#, c, unmanaged, managed

I'm working on a project that combines a very large open source project (OSP) written in C and attempting to build a front end in C#. I'm currently compiling the OSP with Visual Studio 2012 Express and generating all the .exe's, .dll's,etc from this project.

**How should I perform the integration?** (Remember I have full access to the .h/.c files) I attempted using the IJW (It Just Works) method, but it didn't appear to allow me to import the references for my freshly compiled .dll's. Apart from that, I'm not sure how to execute the various functions within C# (apart from sending command line commands to the .exe's, which I would prefer not to do....)

Do I need to compile the OSP with special options/parameters for IJW, or would it require code rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

For DLL written in C, you need to write the equivalent declarations in C# instead of adding reference to that DLL.

This is called **PInvoke**.

```
class ABC
{
    [DllImport("abc.dll")]
    public static extern int FuncX(int x, int y);
}
```

Comment: Note that the `[DllImport]` must be inside the class, but cannot be inside any methods.

Comment: Is there any other cleaner way than this? (Or at least, a cleaner declaration), feels very messy

Comment: Write a class to hold the imported methods. It costs only 2 lines per method, which I do not think it is messy.

Comment: You cannot directly access unmanaged code from managed code, you can do it only by using p/invoke, as @linquize suggests. If you don't want to use [DllImport], your option is to write a C++/CLI (mixed managed/unmanaged) wrapper for the C classes and methods. i.e. http://bit.ly/JkGF7K